# Passing a props to Functional Component in route ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-functional-component

I have an route as below:

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect
    path="/google/auth/success"
    to={{pathname: "/sign-in", state: {propsTest: "Sample property send"}}}
  />
  <Route
    component={SignIn}
    exact
    path="/sign-in"
  />
  ...
</Switch>
```

The SignIn component is a Functional Component as below:

```
const SignIn = ({ isLoggedIn, authorization, signin, error }) => {
...
return (
...
)
}
```

I want to pass propsTest to this SignIn component, I tried as:

```
const SignIn = ({ isLoggedIn, authorization, signin, error, propsTest }) => {

...
console.log("Property passed to SignIn", propsTest);
...
return (
...
)
}
```

How can I get propsTest in the SignIn component. I found some example for Class Component but not Functional Component.

Comment: I recommend you that you use a global state like redux or the context api. It is much better than using react router state.

Comment: This component should be no rendered, I just need it to redirect and call an redux defined action. Do you recommend me any best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it would be the same regardless if the component is a class-based or functional component, they operate with the same API/interface, i.e. props.

You can create an anonymous component that proxies the route props to the rendered component and then also pass any additional props you like.

```
<Route
  component={routeProps => <SignIn {...routeProps} routeProps.propsTest />}
  exact
  path="/sign-in"
/>
```

Comment: It's worked if I changed code to this:

<Route
  component={routeProps => <SignIn {...routeProps} routeProps.propsTest />}
  exact
  path="/sign-in"
/>

Tks for your help.

Comment: It's worked for me Bro, Thank you:
              <Route
                path="/reports"
                component={(props) => <Reports MenuOpend={"true"}/>}
              />